# how to load a css for Safari only?

Tags: html, css, safari

how can I load a css file only for Safari browser ?
I usually use just this (without javascript)

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
  <link href="ie8.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

for internet explorer 8. 
Thanks

Comment: Have you found a bug that appears in Safari, but not Chrome, Mobile Safari, Konqueror or any other WebKit based browser? (Hint: Try to find a way to deal with the issue in your main stylesheet. Browser sniffing leads to dooooom.)

Comment: Which version of Safari?  Which version of Chrome? (there are a few hundred)  Make sure you have the latest versions — should be 5.0 and 5.0.375.70 respectively at present.  If those don't match, you may as well check against Chrome version 6.0.437.3.

Comment: yes I have the last version (5.0). If you check the link I passed, you can see the different spacing. (The latest of Chrome, it upgrades automatically).

Comment: I'm not seeing any spacing discrepancies jumping out at me.  Screenshot?

Comment: sorry, the home pages are the same indeed. The differences come when you open an article. This is the link: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/imageSpacing.png

Comment: Still can't reproduce it with Windows builds: http://reisio.com/temp/dbcd.png — might be able to check in Mac OS later.

Comment: yeah exactly. Safari and Chrome have both the same spacing. And it differs from Firefox. Compare Firefox with Safari or Firefox with Chrome.

Comment: Did you have time to see the discrepancies ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen a need to in ages (like Safari 2).  Make a new question about the actual problem you're having and someone can probably tell you how to fix it with nothing but redundant CSS or less.

Comment: Also the small pictures on the frontpage anyway.. in Safari and Chrome the spacing is different.

Comment: Flexbox is still (late 2014, Safari 7) pretty broken in Safari. Works fine in Chrome.

Answer (score 6):

Real simple  bit of PHP. Going to be an alternative for ASP too:

```
<?php
    $browser = get_browser();
    if(strtolower($browser->browser) == 'safari') {
        echo '<link href="safari.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />';
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Im not sure, but maybe you linked to ie8.css and not safari.css

Comment: Look at the other answers/comments, it should be obvious.

Comment: Yes I know that, but I have still answered the question given. He might not have wanted to bug check his CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [CSS Browser selector plugin](http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/). It's really easy to implement and use, just write some special rules in your CSS, no extra stylesheets or anything. I use it and it works great!

Hope it helps :)